# Display double pages using turn.js

Tags: javascript, html, page-flipping

I want to  display two pages on a page load so it gives the impression the book is already opened.
If for example, I want to start the page display from page 2 & 3 I would use code like this:

```
 $("#book").turn({page:2});
```

The above code works while loading the book, but it goes to page1 when I go back from page 2 and 3. Please help me to avoid this problem.

[[link to turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/)]

Comment: Why do you have a page one if you never want to show it?

Answer (score 3):

I got working by the below code :

```
$("#book").bind("start", function(event, pageObject) {
        if (pageObject.next == 1) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $('#book').turn('page', 2).turn('stop');

                        }
    });
```